# Get start date of marriage through a Wikidata SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to change this query which only provides the start date of marriage for one item (`wd:Q42`)

```
WHERE {wd:Q42 p:P26 ?statement.   
       ?statement ps:P26 ?spouse;
                  pq:P580 ?starttime;
                  pq:P582 ?endtime.   
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". } 
} 
ORDER BY (?starttime)
```

to work for multiple items (e.g. all writers, all citizens of US).

Comment: Just replace `wd:Q42` with a variable (e.g. `?x`) and then state something about that variable, (e.g. `?x wdt:P106 wd:Q36180.` for writers or `?x wdt:P27 wd:Q30.` for citizens of US).

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable (`?foo`) instead of `wd:Q42`.

Then you have three options:

- Leave it like that to query *all* items.
  (Not a good idea if the additional triple patterns aren’t restrictive enough.)
- Add triple patterns using the `?variable` to narrow down which items to query.
  (Just like you did with `?statement`.)
- Provide a list of subjects that should be queried (using [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)).

Example for querying writers (occuption = [Q36180](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q36180)):

```
SELECT ?writerLabel ?spouseLabel ?starttimeLabel ?endtimeLabel
WHERE {

  VALUES ?writer { wd:Q42 wd:Q47087 }
  
  ?writer p:P26 ?statement_spouse ;
          p:P106 ?statement_occupation .
  
  ?statement_occupation ps:P106 wd:Q36180 .
  
  ?statement_spouse ps:P26 ?spouse ;
                    pq:P580 ?starttime ;
                    pq:P582 ?endtime .   

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 

} 
ORDER BY ?starttime
LIMIT 10
```

By commenting out the `VALUES` line, you would query all writers instead of just the two listed.

---

Note that your query *requires* an end time. To also find ongoing marriages, you can use `OPTIONAL` for that triple pattern:

```
  ?statement_spouse ps:P26 ?spouse ;
                    pq:P580 ?starttime .

  OPTIONAL {
    ?statement_spouse pq:P582 ?endtime .
  }
```